# What's a good stepper motor to use with ROS?

Tags: ros, actuator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm looking for a stepper motor w/encoder that works with ROS. Does anyone know of a good one that has documentation about how to use it with ROS?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279453/what%27s-a-good-stepper-motor-to-use-with-ros?/) by [CodeMade](https://answers.ros.org/users/28261/codemade/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-01-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-01-10**:
Unless we know what you're trying to do with it it's impossible to answer. Plus the motor itself is largely unconnected to ros. You probably want to ask about a good stepper motor controller that works with ros.

**Comment by [CodeMade](https://answers.ros.org/users/28261/codemade/) on 2018-01-10**:
I’m building a robot arm. I want to be able to get positional feedback like I can win the dynamixel servos. What’s  good stepper motor controller to use for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you'd like to build and 5/6 axis serial robot you might want to take a look at the BCN3D Moveo robot, it is open source (mechanics, eletronics etc.) and fully ROS compatible.

https://github.com/BCN3D

You can find the bill of materials here:
https://github.com/BCN3D/BCN3D-Moveo/blob/master/BOM/BCN3D%20Moveo%20BOM.pdf

---

Originally posted by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) with karma: 1505 on 2018-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0